# Phonegap javascript globalization detect languages and redirect to .html files

Tags: javascript, cordova, globalization

i know this was a topic before but i can´t find a proper solution for it.

I want to detect the language on the devices with phonegap, so i can redirect the user to the right indexLanguageX.html document.

I´ve got this code from the phonegap documentation:

```
function checkLanguage() {
  navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
    function (language) {alert('language: ' + language.value + '\n');},
    function () {alert('Error getting language\n');}
  );
}
```

This should check the preferred language and alert it, right?
But it doesn´t work on my android device..
I also tried it with the phonegap alert version, doesn´t work either.

Can somebody tell me how i can get this to work?

After i get the alert, i still need to do the redirect. I thought this would work with something like:

```
 function (language) {if (language.value=us_en) {  
   window.locaton="indexLanguageX.html"}},
```

Comment: I used a newer Phonegap version and set the permissions and it worked.. but still don´t know how to redirect correcly

Answer (score 0):

figured it out with some help from another topic

```
function checkLanguage() {
navigator.globalization.getPreferredLanguage(
   function (language)
   {
       if(language.value == "English")
       {
           window.location.replace("NewDocument.html");
       }
   },
   function ()
   {
       alert('Error getting language\n');
   }
 );
}
```